# Persistently Filtering Out Application Traffic in Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

Whenever I start `Fiddler`, I see traffic from all of the applications on my system but it's very rarely the case that I want this. Usually what I want is to only see requests made by applications I am debugging. In order to achieve this, I leave Fiddler running all the time and whenever I want to see what happened with a request I can just open it up and see.

I can filter requests by right-clicking on an entry -> Filter -> Hide '`<application name>`'. Although this works fine, it is cleared when Fiddler is restarted.

**How can I persist filters that filter out traffic from a certain application?**

I tried using the Filters tab but this is very limited and one of the missing features is what I detailed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by creating custom rules. In order to do this, in Fiddler, go to Rules -> Customize Rules. You can choose Yes to install the `FiddlerScript Editor` plugin if you want but this is not necessary. Just click No when asked and a file named **CustomRules.js** will be opened using Notepad.

This file allows you to program all sorts of rules into Fiddler, from adding headers to outgoing requests to monitoring the time taken for a response to be received. Further details on it can be found [here](https://fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/dev/scriptsamples.asp).

In order to filter out a certain application, scroll down to the `OnBeforeRequest` method and paste the following code in:

```
if (oSession["X-PROCESSINFO"] && (
    oSession["X-PROCESSINFO"].StartsWith("firefox") ||
    oSession["X-PROCESSINFO"].StartsWith("outlook") ||
false)) 
    { 
        oSession["ui-hide"] = "FiddlerScript> Hiding unimportant process";
    }
```

This piece of code tells Fiddler to hide all requests coming from Mozilla Firefox or Microsoft Outlook. If you want to add / update / delete any application here, all you need to do is copy / update / delete lines that contain the `StartsWith` method.

The first condition will filter out all the requests that do not come from an application. This is the case for requests made from Fiddler's `Composer` tab.